# Can I delete an older version of node?

Tags: node.js, linux

Due to lack of disk space I want to remove old or unused folders.
I found out that there is still 14.15.0 node folder even though 15.1.0 is the current version I use.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 72M Nov  4 18:26 /usr/local/n/versions/node/15.1.0/bin/node
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 71M Oct 27 12:23 /usr/local/n/versions/node/14.15.0/bin/node
```

Is it safe to delete it?

Comment: if you are using a **node version manager** (= nvm) you may use that to remove the older version. I see `/n/` in the path of binary file - you can [use it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) to remove the old one. e.g `n rm 0.9.4 v0.10.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using a **node version manager** (= nvm) you may use that to remove the older version.

I see `/n/` in the path of binary file - you can [use it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) to remove the old one.

[**Removing Versions**](https://github.com/tj/n#removing-versions)

```
# Remove some cached versions:
n rm 0.9.4 v0.10.0
# Removing all cached versions except the current version:
n prune
```

Comment: thanks I'll definitely try node version manager!